# Debug Event being "used" in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, debugging, events, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with  the user interface on project I'm working on. It involves "nodes" and connecting them together. I have the connecting of two nodes together tied to pressing a button on an initial node and then clicking the other node to connect to it. The latter half is implemented by checking for when `Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown` then joining the initial node with the node you last hovered over.

This works fine most of the time however I noticed that sometimes when you clicked on another node it would not join them together instantaneously, but until you click off of the node. After doing `Debug.Log(Event.current.type)` it showed that sometimes the event was coming up as "used" when I clicked, instead of "mouseDown" and as such would not perform the join code until I clicked somewhere else. It seems to only happen for some nodes.

Here are two gifs of the behaviour with the console output:

[image: Short demo]

[image: Longer demo]

Problem code:

```
private bool detectEscape()
{
    Debug.Log(Event.current.type);
    return (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown);
}
```

This function is returning False sometimes on mouse clicks due to the event being "used" sometimes. It is called in the GUI.

Know of any reason what causes the current event to be used? I do comparisons like above in a number of places in my code. Could that be what is causing the current event to be used? How do I avoid it?

Am I using the Event system correctly?

Know of a better way to capture mouse clicks? Using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` unfortunately isn't an option as it only works when the game is running and this program is meant to be an extension to the editor.

Otherwise, know of a way to put a break point in Unity 3D's source code so that I can put one in the the function `Event.Use()` and determine what is consuming the mouse event?

Comment: Adding the source code is all fine and stuff. But adding the relevant code as short snippet inside here is also very appreciated. Not everybody wants/has the time to dig through all your source code.

Comment: plus external links can break, and in the case of github future changes may render it unusable in  context of this particular question, hence the rule to put relevant code into the question itself

Comment: Thanks. Good points. The edit better?

Comment: You debug Event.current.type, after which you return it with a new value ?

Comment: I'm printing to the console the type then comparing it to the MouseDown event. The problem is that the function should be returning True when I click but it isn't at times. The problem persists if I take out the `Debug.Log` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are calling detectEscape from OnGUI somewhere, right? The current event is only valid during OnGUI. Additionally, OnGUI can be called multiple times per frame, with different current events. Sometimes the event type might be Repaint, sometimes it might be MouseDown, sometimes it might be something else. So if the event type is not MouseDown, you don't want to assume that the mouse is not down; the mouse might still be down but a different event might be occurring.

Comment: Your answer has helped me solve this. You were right about not assuming the mouse might not be down. I think perhaps the problem might have been that the event system was updating the current event mid repaint/render and as such would overwrite the mouse down event. 

The way I've ended up fixing this was by capturing the `Event.current.type` at the start of my draw function and then applying it globally to all the nodes, etc.